# Get Values where records not found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with top 3 products per industry

I also have a customer table with products they have purchased including what industry they belong to

I need a query which will join the tables and only return products not associated with the customer based on industry
ie. CID 001 belongs to the Retail industry, it currently has product copper. Based on the industry table it is missing Silver and Gold.

Really stuck with this one and any help would be appreciated.

SQL 2016

Thanks in Advance

FYI.. having some issues with the formatting, 1st table below is the Industry, 2nd table is the Customer, 3rd is the Result(just for CID 001) of the query needed

| Industry | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Retail | Copper |
| Retail | Silver |
| Retail | Gold |
| Oil | Blue |
| Oil | Red |
| Oil | Gold |

| CID | Industry | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Retail | Copper |
| 002 | Retail | Silver |
| 002 | Retail | Gold |
| 003 | Oil | Blue |
| 004 | Oil | Red |
| 005 | Oil | Gold |

| CID | Industry | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Retail | Silver |
| 001 | Retail | Gold |

Comment: *"SQL 2015"* There is no SQL Server 2015. There were releases in 2014 and 2016, but there was no a release in 2015.

Comment: Sorry about that, 2016

Comment: It seems like you should have a customer table that tells you what industry the customer is in (along with other information

Comment: Do you have a `Product` table?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use `except`.

In the first select you add all products using `cross apply` and then remove all you have in `Customer` using `except`

```
select c.CID, c.Industry, i.Product from Customer c
cross apply Industry i
where c.Industry = i.Industry
except
select CID, Industry, Product from Customer
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but if rename your second table to Orders, and add a Customers table that has the CID and Industry of the Customer, you could do the following

```
SELECT C.CID,
    I.Industry,
    I.product
FROM Industry I
INNER JOIN Customers C ON C.Industry = I.Industry
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT O.CID
        FROM Orders O
        WHERE O.cid = C.cid
            AND O.Product = I.Product
        )
ORDER BY C.cid,
    I.Industry,
    I.Product
```